# Debug fails but works in other cases

Tags: c#

WHy do I always get |Access is denied| exception during debug ?

```
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
   string module=p.MainModule.Filename;
}
```

Whatever process it is, the exeption's always called.
But it works if I just start without debugging. 
I'd like to get the full path of the process by the way/.

Answer (score 3):

The Access is denied error (Win32Exception to be exact) happens because you're querying a reference to a process that is no longer running. `GetProcesses` returns an array. If a process terminates after the list is returned, you will get this exception if you try to query the process.

It is just a coincidence that it works without debugging.

To reproduce try this. Start notepad. Run the following code.

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
Console.WriteLine("press enter");
Console.ReadLine();
foreach (var p in processes) Console.WriteLine(p.MainModule.FileName);
```

Close notepad when the app outputs "press enter". When you press enter you'll get the exception when trying to query the Process instance for notepad.